# polymer core-animated-pages how to set background with scrollable content

Tags: css, polymer

I am using core-animated-pages. Some of the the content on the pages will need to be scrolled. I want to set the background color for the pages and I want the background color to cover the scrolled area and not just the current viewport. How do I accomplish this?

More specifically I have:

```
<core-animated-pages flex transitions="cross-fade-all">
<div>Some small content</div>
<div>Some long text that will need to be scrolled</div>
<div>Another page</div>
</core-animated-pages>
```

So how do I style so that the background color will cover the scrolled text?

@jeff provides a large part of the answer in specifying relative on the div. Additionally I used the following CSS to position the element clear of title bar above and to ensure the background covers the reminder of the page.

```
#instructions {
  background: #FFF59D;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 200px);
  top:+30px;
  padding:10px;
  width:calc(100% - 24px);
}
```

The pixels subtracted from the % values and the top:+ allow for a menu bar at the top and the padding on the body -- these will need to be adjust depending on the height of the menu bar and the padding.

Now I would like to wrap the divs in paper-shadow but I find when I do this I lose the background. How can I apply a paper-shadow effect to the divs?

Answer (score 0):

The `<content>` within `<core-animated-pages>` is [styled](https://github.com/Polymer/core-animated-pages/blob/master/core-animated-pages.css#L16) with `position: absolute` + `top/right/bottom/left: 0`. You're not providing the rest of your HTML structure and any other styles that you have defined, but I'm assuming that's what's causing what you're seeing.

Try styling the DOM element that represents the page to use `position: relative` (you can do this by assigning it the Polymer-shorthand `relative` attribute):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Polymer core-animated-pages Demo</title>
    <style>
      core-animated-pages > div {
        background-color: orange;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <script src="//www.polymer-project.org/webcomponents.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="//www.polymer-project.org/components/core-animated-pages/core-animated-pages.html">
    
    <core-animated-pages selected="1" transitions="cross-fade-all">
      <div>Some small content</div>
      <div relative>
        <h1>Blah</h1><h1>Blah</h1><h1>Blah</h1><h1>Blah</h1><h1>Blah</h1><h1>Blah</h1><h1>Blah</h1><h1>Blah</h1><h1>Blah</h1><h1>Blah</h1><h1>Blah</h1><h1>Blah</h1><h1>Blah</h1><h1>Blah</h1><h1>Blah</h1><h1>Blah</h1><h1>Blah</h1><h1>Blah</h1>
      </div>
      <div>Another page</div>
    </core-animated-pages>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks. Specifying relative on the div was what I was missing. I added some additional markup which allowed me to get the background to cover the rest of the page while leaving space for a menu bar above. I'll edit my post to show this.